# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error and Autocomplete dropdown closing when mouse over for my Autocomplete in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am binding list to Autocomplete control, after binding dropdown is showing but when select item from dropdown list it is not selecting and showing Maximum call stack size exceeded error,

and when i mouse over on autocomplete dropdown, the dropdown is closing, here i am proving my code, please tel me where i did mistake.

HTML Code:

```
<div style="width: 25%; display: inline-block;" data-bind="foreach: TaskList" id="dvmotherboardsearch">
  <input style="width: 100%" type="text" id="search" data-bind="value: name, autoComplete: { label: name, value: id }" class="gray search" />
</div>
```

JS File:

```
self.memumorysearchlist = function (data, event) {
        motherbord.length = 0;
        var manufactureUrl;
        selectManufacturer = $('#manufacturer').val();
        selectChiplist = $('#model').val();
        if (selectManufacturer !== "" && selectChiplist !== "")
            manufactureUrl = "https://api.pcpartpicker.com/api/2015.1/part/category/list/?apikey=5612661951b24c58979b7bb372c2a1f0809e2dc9&part_type=motherboard" + "&m=" + selectManufacturer + "&c=" + selectChiplist;            
        $.ajax({
            url: "services/MemoryFinderDataProvider.asmx/PcPartpickerList",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{ 'partlisturl' : '" + manufactureUrl + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (data) {

            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj;
                var xmlDoc = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                var xml1 = $(xmlDoc.parts);
                for (var i = 0; i < xml1.length; i++) {
                    obj = {};
                    obj['label'] = xml1[i].name;
                    obj['value'] = xml1[i].slug;
                    motherbord.push(obj);
                }
                $("#search").autocomplete({
                    source: motherbord,
                    minLength: 0,
                }).focus(function () {
                    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
                });
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#search").autocomplete("search", "");
                });                   
            }

        });
        $('#ui-id-1').css('height', '400px');
        $('#ui-id-1').css('overflow', 'scroll');            
    }
```

Comment: The question is rather unclear. First up, the code contains both too much- and too little code. Too much, because there's all sorts of things that can be stubbed out and are probably irrelevant to the problem itself. Too little, because it's not enough to repro. Please do some root cause analysis yourself first, trim the code down (and add some) to get an [mcve], and update the question.

Comment: @Jeroen Now see the question it is updated

Comment: You've changed nearly nothing!? Did you even read my comment and the link in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had wrote

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
                    source: motherbord,
                    minLength: 0,
                }).focus(function () {
                    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
                });
```

in end of self.memumorysearchlist in $(document).ready(function () {});

and it's work fine..